# Environment-less alternative to "comment" environment?

Tags: comments

I am searching for a standardized way of inserting inline author-only notes into LaTeX documents, that doesn't require the visual overhead of the `comment` environment.

---

I often want to insert small notes into documents, that I can easily hide from final output, while retaining them for my "personal" version.

The `comment` package provides just that; However, its environment-based syntax isn't particularly suitable for small inline notes, such as

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
\begin{comment}
  Labook p431.
\end{comment}
invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
```

It would be more preferable, to have something compact like the `\footnote` command. Technically that's easy to do, e.g.

```
\usepackage{ifdraft}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\inlinecomment}[1]{%
  \ifoptionfinal{}{\textcolor{black!50!white}{/* #1 */}}%
}
```

but I'd prefer a solution, that is predefined by some package for the sake of portability across documents.

From my experience, if it is a per-document hack, I *will* eventually change the name of the command, or its argument signature, and then bite myself when I try to combine contents from different documents.

Comment: what about `verb{...}` or `verb+...+` or what ever delimiter you like

Comment: You can use todonotes.

Comment: I tend to use the `fixme` package, configured in the right manner, then notes can more or less be added everywhere (in todonotes, they cannot since it is using marginpar internally), it's even easy to add the todonotes "trail" to fixme notes

Comment: packages change, so using a package rather than a personal macro is also a "per-document hack", in some cases (say over 20years span) it is even less safe.

Comment: This is a recurrent issue , but at the end of day the less intrusive, most practical,reliable and portable IMHO is  just `% comment`. If you want print the comment sometimes, you only need a method of  go and back from `%comment` to  `\%comment without touch the `\%` in the normal text.  For instance, you can use `%% comment`  and search and replace safely `%%` by `\%\%`, or if you use comments only at the start of the lines, with a good editor with you can search carriage returns followed by %.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little package that provides both an inline comment (`\nb`) and an environment-style block comment (`\NB`). You can style the comment by redefining `\nbstyle`.

By default comments are hidden; if you pass the `show` option to the package then they will be shown, as in the example.

## Package

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{notabene}[2022/04/11 simple
inline comments, can be switched on or off]

\newif\ifnb
\nbfalse

\DeclareOption{show}{\nbtrue}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\NewDocumentCommand{\nbstyle}{}{\sffamily}

\NewDocumentCommand{\nb}{ m }{\ifnb{\nbstyle#1}\fi}

\RequirePackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{NB}{\nb{\BODY}}

\endinput
```

## Example document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[show]{notabene}
\begin{document}
I am saying this.\nb{But I \emph{mean} this.}

I could list several ideas.
\begin{NB}
    Existentialism?
    Transubstantiation?
    Denuclearization?
\end{NB}
\end{document}
```

Comment: since you're assuming a recent version of the kernel with the xparse extensions, it'd be possible to use the new syntax for the environment, too: `\NewDocumentEnvironment{NB}{+b}{\nb{#1}}`

Answer (score 0):

This is an option using the `scontents` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scontents}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
\section{Document with hidden comments}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
\begin{scontents}
  Labook p431.
\end{scontents}
invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
\Scontents{Labook p433}
some more text here
\section{Only comments}
% now print
\getstored[1]{contents}\par
\getstored[2]{contents}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Modifying package options `[print-all]`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[print-all]{scontents}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
\section{Document with hidden comments}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
\begin{scontents}
  Labook p431.
\end{scontents}
invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
\Scontents{Labook p433}
some more text here
\section{Only comments}
% now print
\getstored[1]{contents}\par
\getstored[2]{contents}
\end{document}
```

[image: print-all]